# python len() fieldcalculation

Tags: python, field, calculation, arcpy

I am trying to write a script in Arcgis pro in the field calculation. The values from the other fields are to be summarized in a new field. For values below 60 meters the value should be set to 60. All other values should be summarized. In addition, the type designations are to be written in capital letters. If there are no values in any of the fields, "No data" should be displayed.
Unfortunately i can not find the error..

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated !

value (!Typ1!, !Typ2!, !Typ3!, !Shape_area!, !total!)

```py
def value (Fieldvalue1, Fieldvalue2, Fieldvalue3, Fieldvalue4, Fieldvalue5):
    
       
        if len(Fieldvalue1) > 1:
            combine = str(Fieldvalue1) + "_" + Fieldvalue4
            return combine
    
        elif len(Fieldvalue2) > 1:
            combine = str(Fieldvalue2) + "_" + Fieldvalue4
            return combine
    
        elif len(Fieldvalue3) > 1:
            combine = str(Fieldvalue3) + "_" + Fieldvalue4
            return combine

        if Fieldvalue4 < 60:
            return "60"

        else:
            return "No data"


        Fieldvalue5 = Fieldvalue5.upper()
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Also, where are you calling the `value` function?

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert Fieldvalue4 to str before addition or to int (if it is str) in the if comparison expression.

Comment: I have now inserted the Fieldvalue4 = int(Fieldvalue4) before the if at the beginning.        But now comes this error message:                                                                      ERROR 000539: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 6, in comStr
TypeError: must be str, not int
 Failed to execute (CalculateField).

Answer (score 0):

Fields have length property:

```
def value (Fieldvalue1, Fieldvalue2, Fieldvalue3, Fieldvalue4, Fieldvalue5):

   
    if Fieldvalue1.length > 1:
        combine = str(Fieldvalue1) + "_" + Fieldvalue4
        return combine

    elif Fieldvalue2.length > 1:
        combine = str(Fieldvalue2) + "_" + Fieldvalue4
        return combine

    elif Fieldvalue3.length > 1:
        combine = str(Fieldvalue3) + "_" + Fieldvalue4
        return combine

    if Fieldvalue4 < 60:
        return "60"

    else:
        return "No data"

    # Dead code here
    Fieldvalue5 = Fieldvalue5.upper()
```

Comment: where must the code (Fieldvalue5.upper()) be inserted?

Comment: Well depends on what are you trying to achieve and on the logic you are implementing...If   the instruction have to be ran in any case you can move it as first line of the function